# Table django_session don't exists when I try use admin with mysql

Tags: python, mysql, django

I'm new with django 1.10 using mysql (5.6.17) (WAMP 2.5) and Python 3.5 under Windows 8.1

I configured fine the mysql connector, I made my models, made `makemigrations myapp` and `migrate myapp`, using manage.py terminal with Pycharm.

When I try to acces in admin web page, I have this message (trabajo is my app inside my project: programa)

**Exception Value:**

```
(1146, "Table 'programa.django_session' doesn't exist")
```

In my settings.py file have:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
```

The apps block:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'trabajo',
]
```

To connect the database:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME' : 'programa',
        'USER' : 'myownuser',
        'PASSWORD' : 'myownpassword',
        'HOST' : '',
        'PORT' : '',
    }
}
```

Why have this error in the admin page? What can I do to solve this?

Thanks in advance. Any help is welcome!! ;-)

Gustavo.

Answer (score 11):

if all you did was "migrate myapp", then you only created the tables for your app. I think a plain "migrate" will create all the tables for Django and it's contributed modules.

Comment: Thank buddy! I made `makemigrations` and `migrate` and works!!

Answer (score 7):

Run command:

```
python manage.py migrate sessions
```

Comment: This will not work !

Below worked -
python manage.py migrate

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the same problem, my issue was that migration history had recorded that it had successfully created a table for `session` even though it hadn't actually done so on my MySQL DB.

I was able to fix it by running command:

```
python manage.py migrate --fake sessions zero
```

Then:

```
python manage.py migrate sessions
```

Answer (score 1):

### I got this error:

```
File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 259, in query_mysql.connection.query(self, query) MySQLdb._exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1146, "Table
'database_name.django_session' doesn't exist")
```

### and solved by the following command:

```
python manage.py migrate sessions
```